# What is the difference between SUA (Special Use Airspace) and FUA (Flexible Use Airspace)?

Tags: terminology, airspace, special-use-airspace

The EUROCONTROL Concept of the Flexible Use of Airspace ([FUA](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Flexible_Use_of_Airspace)) is that:

> 1. an ASM concept currently applied in the ECAC area and based on the fundamental principle that airspace should no longer be designated as
>      either pure civil or military airspace, but rather be considered as
>      one continuum in which all airspace user requirements have to be
>      accommodated
> 2. an airspace management concept applied in the European Civil Aviation Conference area on the basis of the “Airspace management
>      handbook for the application of the concept of the flexible use of
>      airspace” issued by Eurocontrol

EUROCONTROL also defines Special Use Airspace ([SUA](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Special_Use_Airspace)) as:

> Airspace of defined dimensions identified by an area on the surface of
>   the earth wherein activities must be confined because of their nature
>   and/or wherein limitations may be imposed upon aircraft operations
>   that are not a part of those activities.

**Question**: what is the relationship exists between SUA and FUA? Can they be considered as the same thing? Is SUA a special type of FUA or vice-versa?
What is the difference essentially?

Comment: You can think of it as flexible use of special use airspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexible Use *of* Airspace is a concept rather than a part of airspace (which SUA is), where the whole airspace is used for both restricted and unrestricted (civil) activities. [According to FAA](http://www.icao.int/RO_EURNAT/Other%20Meetings%20Seminars%20and%20Workshops/Flexible%20Use%20of%20Airspace%20(FUA)%20Workshops/Flexible%20Use%20of%20Airspace%20-%20Demystified/2-3-4%20USA%20Joint%20Use%20Airspace%20Concept.pdf):

> • The FAA version of Flexible Use of Airspace (FUA) is called “Joint Use Airspace”
>
> • Although not defined as such, the domestic United States could be labeled as being completely FUA airspace.

The Special Use Airspace (SUA) is a portion of the Flexible Use Airspace (FUA), in which [unrelated activities have been restricted](http://prudata.webfactional.com/wiki/index.php/SUA):

> In accordance with the FUA concept, Special Use Airspace is a defined portion of airspace which may be temporarily reserved for specific activities which require the restriction or segregation of other traffic.

Basically, in a FUA, SUA will be a temporary restriction (rather than a permanent one). Eurocontrol also [says the same thing](http://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/flexible-use-airspace):

> The EUROCONTROL Concept of the Flexible Use of Airspace (FUA) is that:
>
> Airspace is no longer designated as purely "civil" or "military" airspace, but considered as one continuum and allocated according to user requirements.
>
> Any necessary airspace segregation is temporary, based on real-time usage within a specific time period.

Related concept is [Advanced Flexible Use of Airspace](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Advanced_Flexible_Use_of_Airspace) in which SUA is allotted in real time.

> An airspace management concept in which airspace is managed as a single entity and in which there are no fixed structures and airspace reservations for special airspace activity are allocated in real time.