# Where to find comprehensive description of Special Use Airspaces (SUAs)?

Tags: terminology, airspace, special-use-airspace

Can you suggest me some document or website where I can learn about Special Use Airspaces?

My goal is to understand the following topics:

- SUA definition
- Types of SUAs
- SUA pubblication
- SUA creation and activation
- Documents in which SUA geometry and time information are stored.

If you know some website, pdf or book where I can learn about SUA I would be very glad. Feel free to add to the answer also your suggestions and knowledge about what you know relative to SUAs (especially about where geometry and time infos are stored).

Note: I know [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_use_airspace) or [eurocontrol](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Special_Use_Airspace) have some definitions but they are too concise for me. I would like to get something quite detailed and complete.

Comment: `SUA definition` what's not clear from [your previous](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32692/1467) question?

Comment: As you can read on the question I would like to have a document/website with a comprehensive description of SUAs... the answer you gave me are clear but come from people. I would like to have somehow the bibliography where they got the infos from.

Comment: This page has SUA geometry and time information for active SUAs. https://sua.faa.gov/sua/siteFrame.app

Comment: Which country/countries are you interested in?

Comment: As many as possible... especially EU and USA but also South America, Asia, Oceania :)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of Special Use Airspace according to Wikipedia are:

> Is an area designated for operations of a nature such that limitations may be imposed on aircraft not participating in those operations. Often these operations are of a military nature.

Types of SUA's

> restricted airspace, prohibited airspace, military operations areas (MOA) and temporary flight restriction.

Two relevant PDF documents:
https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7400.8SBasic.pdf

https://www.faasafety.gov/files/events/GL/GL05/2007/GL0515004/CH_3_Sec_4.pdf

Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_use_airspace

Comment: Hi, yes I need much more information of that because that is what I already know (as stated in my question).